# Uploading a file to azure file storage using C# makes all the rest of the files in the directory 0 length

Tags: c#, azure, file

I am using the following method to upload a file to Azure file storage. What it does is that sometimes it wipes out files already in the directory, setting their length to 0. The new file is uploaded with correct length, but the old ones are with length set to 0. It does this 8 of 10 times, without throwing any error.

```
  public static bool UploadFile(string fileName, byte[] fileInBytes, string directory, string sunDirectory)
    {

        if (fileInBytes == null && fileInBytes.Length == 0)
        {
            Logger.Log("file is zero length");
            return false;
        }

        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;

        try
        {
            storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(documentsConnectionString);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Log("can't use storage account! " + ex.Message);
            return false;
        }

        CloudFileClient fileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();

        CloudFileShare share = fileClient.GetShareReference(fileShareReference);

        if (share.Exists())
        {
            try
            {
                CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();

                CloudFileDirectory directoryRef;

                directoryRef = rootDir.GetDirectoryReference(directory);

                directoryRef.CreateIfNotExists();

                CloudFileDirectory subDirectoryRef;
                subDirectoryRef = directoryRef.GetDirectoryReference(subDirectory);


                subDirectoryRef.CreateIfNotExists();

                CloudFile file = subDirectoryRef.GetFileReference(fileName);

                file.UploadFromByteArray(fileInBytes, 0, fileInBytes.Count());

                return true;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Log("Uploading file to azure exception: " + ex.Message);
                return false;
            }                
        }
        else
        {
            Logger.Log("Document share does not exist!");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try using some Console.WriteLine and looking at what the variables contain. A debugger with visual studio would also let you look at the variables contents. It helps me a lot when I can parse through objects while the code is running.

Comment: The above code runs on Azure App service. If it was giving errors, I would have them in the log. What I can't understand is how all the files in the folder are becoming 0 length, as I am not even accessing them? It looks like the whole folder gets screwed when I upload a new file.

Comment: By 0 length do you mean they are truncated. Also, debuggers do wonders

Comment: Exactly - truncated. Files are there, but length is 0.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.

this code

```
 if (fileInBytes == null && fileInBytes.Length == 0)
    {
```

has to be

```
 if (fileInBytes == null || fileInBytes.Length == 0)
    {
```

Otherwise files with zero length are allowed for saving.

Thanks to everyone spend time to look at the question